# How to dynamically generate labels and textboxes using simple for loops in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, label, dynamically-generated

So, i am trying to generate two labels and two textboxes on a button click. Every time i click the button, it should generate a new set of labels and textboxes on the screen.

Here is the Layout

```
Label 1   Textbox 1   Label 2   Textbox 2  Button
```

On every button click, the following should happen

**1 click**

```
Label 1   Textbox 1  Label 2   Textbox 2  Button     

Label 3   Textbox 3  Label 4   Textbox 4
```

**2 clicks**

```
Label 1   Textbox 1  Label 2   Textbox 2  Button 
Label 3   Textbox 3  Label 4   Textbox 4    
Label 5   Textbox 5  Label 6   Textbox 6
```

How can i achieve this.

At present i only see one row of labels and textboxes, they are probably getting overwritten at the same place.

Here is my Code.

```
        button_press++;
        for (int i = 0; i < button_press; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello"); 
            Label book_number = new Label();
            book_number.Text = "Book Number";
            book_number.Style["Position"] = "Relative";
            book_number.Style["Top"] = "0px";
            book_number.Style["Left"] = "0px";
            TextBox textBox_book_number = new TextBox();
            textBox_book_number.Style["Position"] = "Relative";
            textBox_book_number.Style["Top"] = "0px";
            textBox_book_number.Style["Left"] = "10px";
            Label amount = new Label();
            amount.Text = "Amount";
            amount.Style["Position"] = "Relative";
            amount.Style["Top"] = "0px";
            amount.Style["Left"] = "30px";
            TextBox textBox_amount = new TextBox();
            textBox_amount.Style["Position"] = "Relative";
            textBox_amount.Style["Top"] = "0px";
            textBox_amount.Style["Left"] = "45px";

            form1.Controls.Add(book_number);
            form1.Controls.Add(textBox_book_number);
            form1.Controls.Add(amount);
            form1.Controls.Add(textBox_amount);
            form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }
```

Comment: They are not overwritten. The page did not have a memory on what you made on code behind, so on post back is just start from the beginning.

Comment: @Aristos:- How can i fix this.and get the desired layout as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button the page is refreshed so your previously created textbox and label are removed.

I would suggest that you save the textboxes and labels in a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add to the collection on each click of the button and then display the entire collection on your button click

Comment: Can you write some code to demonstrate how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can add controls with JQuery and then post them with Ajax to database, in this theory your button will not refresh page and you don't have losing values problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input besides the button which keeps track of the number of clicks. Set this value to your variable button_press, increment and set the new value to the hidden input. This will increase the count even when the page actually refreshes on each click

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is not server side, it's client side. On the first document.load, create the label/textbox pair.
When the button is clicked, call a javascript function which is in your .aspx, that will create the label/textbox pair.
This will prevent several round trips to the server just for the sake of adding the label/text pair.
Finally I'm sure you want to submit this data to the server. You can use JSON to build the data input in the textboxes and pass all that information with the click of another button named like 'submit data' using a jQuery function which talks to the server or even use javascript's XMLHttpRequest to push the data from client to server.
I know it sounds hard, but you could give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I made the button press variable static and everything worked fine. The key was to retain the session state and by making it static i could achieve it.